# Order of bonuses and penalties to move speed

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement, conditions

Let's say my character has a base land speed of 40 ft. (Human with the *Quick* trait). Unfortunately he gets *blinded* (halves move speed), but to overcome that, he actives his **Acrobat Boots** using one charge to give him a 10 ft. bonus to his move speed.

What order is the *blind* penalty and **Acrobat Boots** bonus applied? What is his actual current move speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Boots give you an enhancement bonus to your **speed**, not to something else like “your current movement rate,” or to “how far you can move this round.” As a result, your **speed** is enhanced, but it's still halved anyway, because blindness halves your **speed** regardless of what else you do to your **speed**.

So your character's current move speed would be (40 + 10) ÷ 2 = **25 ft.**

To be clear, this isn't a matter of order of operations as thought in the question, it's a matter of wording. It depends on what the modifiers are modifying, and their exact wording. If you had an item that let you “move an additional 10 feet when activated”, then it would apply last because it's not modifying the same thing that *blinded* is modifying. In this case *blinded* just *happens* to apply last, but only because it halves your total speed, which includes any enhancements to it. If *blinded* was worded differently (“halve your base speed”, say), it wouldn't be last here.

Comment: Just to clarify, effects that halve your movement like being blinded or slowed are applied last?

Comment: @FrancisJohn Neither — it depends on what the other bonuses are doing, and what they are doing it to, and their exact wording. If you had an item that let you “move an additional 10 feet when activated”, then *it* would apply last because it's not modifying the same thing that *blinded* is modifying. In this case *blinded* happens to apply last, but only because it halves your total speed, which includes any enhancements to it. If *blinded* was worded differently (“halve your base speed”, say), it wouldn't be last here.